# AmCharts ChartCursor hide value on legend

Tags: javascript, html, graph, amcharts

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rjkmu0rn/

When I add a `ChartCursor` to my chart, it displays the value of the points on the legend and, as a result, overlaps on the legend itself.

Any ideas on how to prevent `ChartCursor` from displaying the values on the legend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by adding a `valueFunction` to the legend settings: https://jsfiddle.net/rjkmu0rn/2/

```
legend: {
    "horizontalGap": 50,
    "useGraphSettings": true,
    "valueFunction": function(graphDataItem, valueText) {
      return "";
    }
  }
```

Comment: how do you hide valueText when it is switched off?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `valueText` to be an empty string.

```
  legend: {
    useGraphSettings: true,
    valueText: ""
  }
```